# Excel: YES and NO

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a column with data set "yes" or "no" Say E3:E6, if one of the results in E3:E6 is a NO, I need the result to be a NO.  All four cells need to say Yes in order for the result to be Yes.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK('https://mtbmgmt-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jsample_mtbmanagement_com/Documents/[2023 Scorecard Data.xlsx]Butte'!$E$6),"",('https://mtbmgmt-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jsample_mtbmanagement_com/Documents/[2023 Scorecard Data.xlsx]Butte'!$E$6))

Comment: Thanks to Scott down below, I have made a lot of progress, but now I am trying to figure out how to get a blank result when the cell is blank, but I have some ideas.  As a new user, I'm not exactly sure how to pose the question @Giacomo1968

Comment: You need to add the formula examples you have tried to your question. Please edit your question to show your work. Code in comments is often ignored and hard to read. Editing your question is the way to make this question viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AND()

```
=IF(AND(E3:E6="yes"),"yes","no")
```

If any do not equal `yes` it will return `no`

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do I need to add to the formula to account for wanting blank cells to return a blank result?

Comment: That was not part of the question asked.  But you would nest this if in another that uses OR() to test for `""`

Comment: @ScottCraner These “One more thing!” requests are why you should avoid answering vague scripting request questions like this where no real effort is shown by the original poster.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 if the user had insisted and not asked a follow up question I would have deleted this answer.  This answered what was asked.  I did not see the need for more information.  It was fairly apparent what they wanted.  As to what they tried, well I usually put the formula in the comments on questions like this, but I kept getting yelled at for answering in the comments.  So now if I understand the need and have the time I answer.  If I guess wrong I delete the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner “This answered what was asked. I did not see the need for more information. It was fairly apparent what they wanted.” Yes, they wanted free scripts written from scratch without showing one once of effort. That should not be encouraged.